# Call private method static.private class

Tags: java

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            int num = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine().trim());
            Object o;


        Method[] methods = Inner.class.getEnclosingClass().getMethods();
        for(int i=0;i<methods.length;i++) {
            System.out.println(methods[i].invoke(new Solution(),8));
        }
            // Call powerof2 method here

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static class Inner {
        private class Private {
            private String powerof2(int num) {
                return ((num & num - 1) == 0) ? "power of 2" : "not a power of 2";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to call `powerof2()` method ?
I am getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch` for `invoke`

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: With or without reflection?

Comment: @bradimus i updated my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, things declared in the same top-level class can always access each other:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Inner i = new Inner(); // Create an instance of Inner
        Inner.Private p = i.new Private(); // Create an instance of Private through
                                           // the instance of Inner, this is needed since
                                           // Private is not a static class.

        System.out.println(p.powerof2(2)); // Call the method
    }

    static class Inner {
        private class Private {
            private String powerof2(int num) {
                return ((num & num - 1) == 0) ? "power of 2" : "not a power of 2";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See [Ideone](http://ideone.com/YnZ3Ut)

Comment: how cn i do same using reflection & which approcah is coorect ?

Comment: @manish Why do you want to use reflection? It is usually not very JIT friendly?

Comment: ok, what is the logic behind the code you mentioned i mean i want to know about this in more details

Comment: one more thing let say i have to do something like `Object o =i.new Private()` no will it be possible to call `powerof2()` on `o` ?

Comment: @manish It will be if you cast it back: `((Inner.Private) o).powerof2(...);`

Answer (score 2):

Reflection version:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, SecurityException, NoSuchMethodException {

        Class<?> privateCls = Inner.class.getDeclaredClasses()[0];


        Method powerMethod = privateCls.getDeclaredMethod("powerof2", int.class);

        powerMethod.setAccessible(true);
        Constructor<?> constructor = privateCls.getDeclaredConstructors()[0];
        constructor.setAccessible(true);
        Object instance = constructor.newInstance(new Inner());

        System.out.println(powerMethod.invoke(instance, 2));

    }

    static class Inner {
        private class Private {
            private String powerof2(int num) {
                return ((num & num - 1) == 0) ? "power of 2" : "not a power of 2";
            }
        }
    }
}
```